# C++ Error when for loop is in if else statement when using OpenMP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp

When I am running the following code in visual studio 2015, I got the error on "else" statement that "expected a declaration". I can't figure out why this can't work since I have specified the parallel area.

```
void test(int a) {
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        #pragma omp parallel{
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            cout << i;
        }
        }
    }
    else {
        //#pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
}
```

Without the openMP declaration, the code runs well. Why it happens and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is your parenthesis {}

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int a)
{
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
    }

else
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cout << i;
    }

 }
}

int main()
{
    test(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0123456789Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem is that the { can't be in the same line with #pragma omp parallel.

Comment: @ shen tao  Please accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is cuased by an extra } which makes the else statement one } off from the if statement and the compilier does not know what to do with it

```
void test(int a) 
{
    if (a % 2 == 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            cout << i;
        }
        } //here is the extra }!
    }else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the code without the extra }

```
void test(int a) 
{
    if (a % 2 == 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            cout << i;
        }
    }else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
        {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I noticed that your formatting is a bit odd and it probably helped with you not noticing the extra }

Best of luck! :)

Comment: The extra } is for #pragma omp parallel{, which is to enable the parallel computing

Comment: You cannot put the { on the same line as the pragma.